# Accessing: "curl -I --http1.0 http://www.example.com". Error : curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to Proxy_server

Tags: curl, wireshark

I'm accessing http1.0 protocol in wireshark through curl.
Curl is unable to access browser because of the following error.

> curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to Proxy_server

when I tried this `curl -I --http1.0 http://www.example.com``

In order to get result of 1.0 protocol I needed curl to be working.
As it shows SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to proxy server

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: I'm working on wireshark. As of now all sites use http1.1 protocol. To get http1.0 protocol we need to use curl. While using curl with following phrases " curl -I --http1.0 http://www.google.com" , I'm getting the error which I raised as question.

Comment: I work on proxy server. I think curl is unable to get that but I don't know the exact reason why it is not working